# Prove that if $EX_1^+=\infty$ and $EX_1^-<\infty$, then $\frac{S_n}n\stackrel{a.s.}\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be $i.i.d$ and $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$. Prove that if $EX_1^+=\infty$ and $EX_1^-<\infty$, then $\frac{S_n}n\stackrel{a.s.}\rightarrow\infty$.

How to use the conditions  $EX_1^+=\infty$ and $EX_1^-<\infty$?

---

Solution: Let $X_n^\prime=X_nI_{\{|X_n|\le M\}}$,then use the SLLN and MCT to prove the problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Replace $X_k$ by the truncated random variable $\min(X_k, M)$ and apply the strong law of large numbers. Then let $M \to \infty$.

Comment: I still do not know how to use the conditon $EX_1^+=\infty$ and $EX_1^-<\infty$. Can you give a bit more details? Thank you!

Comment: The second condition allows you to apply the law of large numbers to the truncated sequence. The first condition is needed in the $M \to \infty$ step. As a further hint, note that $X_k \ge \min(X_k, M)$ holds for all $k$. I don't know how I can give any further hints without solving the exercise completely.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I think the hints are very close to the solution.

Comment: Maybe we can use the truncation $X_n^\prime=X_kI_{\{|X_k|\le M\}}$ to solve the problem. The main idea is as the hints provided by Dominik.